# In Java, how can I use mouseClicked without calling mousePressed and mouseReleased?

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm writing a program to draw a bouncing ball, and then the user can draw rectangles on the screen, and the ball bounces off the rectangles.  A flag is set to true in mousePressed, and as long as the flag is true, a rectangle is drawn from the starting point to the current point (using mouseDragged).  The flag is set to false in mouseReleased.  I'll be using mouseClicked to erase the rectangle that is clicked (if there is one).  The problem I'm encountering is that on mouseClicked, mousePressed and mouseReleased are both called.  Is there a way we can make it not do that?

Comment: Could you instead change your mousePressed method to check if the first click is inside a rectangle, and remove that way?

Comment: @dann.dev check on mouse press if the click is inside rectangle? A click aint complete untill press is released. So how is it possible to check for a click inside a press?

Comment: @MukulGoel you don't need to worry about the full click if you cannot draw rectangles that overlap other rectangles, because any press inside a rectangle will be a removal, so as long as your mouseReleased method only sets the flag to false, it doesn't matter where they release the mouse. If you can draw overlapping rectangles, then you want to record the start click x/y and compare with the released position, then you can have a threshold which decides whether it was a click, or whether it was drawing a new rectangle. Make sense?

Comment: @dann.dev makes perfect sense sir. And that is quite similar to approach I have answered with. I was just pointing out the term `check for click inside a press` its not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `mousePressed()` have a check for *is the mouse pressed inside a rectangle??* Use the same function you are using, 
In case of mouse clicked to find out if a rectangle is there or not.

Now if this check is true *dont set the drawRectangleFlag to true*

FYI , the above solution is invalid , in case you want to draw a rectangle inside a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You could have a check in mousePressed to see if the mouse was pressed inside of a rectangle, and if so then don't set the flag.